# Campos estáticos en la clase BufferedImage

Tags: java, poo, imagen, bufferedimage

Tengo algunas dudas con la clase `BufferedImage`: quisiera entender por qué [según su documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) tiene solo campos estáticos.

Pero vi algunos ejemplos que la declaran con parámetros y no entiendo muy bien, soy nuevo en Java.

Answer (score 0):

Esos campos estáticos representan **constantes** que se usan para identificar posibles valores para parámetros que no tienen una representación directa.

Por ejemplo, los campos que tú mencionas se refieren a como se organiza la información de la imagen (bytes por pixel, qué significa cada byte, etc.). Si quieres crear un imagen donde cada pixel tiene 255 valores para rojo, 255 para verde y 255 para azul, pasas `TYPE_INT_RGB` en el constructor.

Obviamente, el constructor lo que recibe es un entero con el número arbitrario asignado a ese campo, pero es mucho más visual y fácil de leer y escribir esto:

```
// Al crear la imagen:
BufferedImage myImage = new BufferedImage(ancho, alto, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

// Dentro del constructor:
switch (imageType) {
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB:
   ...
   break;
case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB:
   ....
}
```

que esto:

```
// Al crear la imagen:
BufferedImage myImage = new BufferedImage(ancho, alto, 5);

// Dentro del constructor:
switch (imageType) {
case 5:
   ...
   break;
case 6:
   ....
}
```

En el primer caso, el nombre ya te indica qué es lo que hace tu código, en el segundo tienes que buscar alguna documentación que te explique que significa cada valor.

De todas formas, a partir de Java 5 esta técnica se sustituyo por el uso de *enums*, que precisamente funcionan como valores constantes directamente.